# Linux: GetDateFormat() and GetTimeFormat() existed C++?

Tags: c++, linux, time

I imported the libraries below.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

I want to converted the part below of the code to Linux C++. How could be?

I have converted `TCHAR` to `std::string`, which is used in `_countof` as a parameter of `GetDateFormat`

```
TCHAR szDate[16];
TCHAR szTime[16];

GetDateFormat(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, 0, NULL, 
            _T("yyyy-MM-dd"), 
            szDate, _countof(szDate)); 

GetTimeFormat ( LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, 0, NULL, 
        _T("hh:mm:ss tt"),
        szTime, _countof(szTime) );
```

Comment: Look up `strftime`, the closest POSIX equivalent of the two.

Comment: I recommend you check out the [standard C++ time functionality](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono), rather than continue using platform-specific functions.

Comment: *"... but does not work"* is not a useful problem statement. You need to state how it does not work. You should also show the compiler command that produced the error.

Comment: @jww updated. Thanks

Comment: Is it a game to vote -1. What is that?. There is no question like this in Stackoverflow. I am trying to test the answers. Continue voting negatively....

Comment: There are many smart programmer but little open minded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`strftime()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/) from `<ctime>`, which is not the same, but a close match to these MSDN functions you mention.

However, I would strongly recommend you to check what C++ provides:

[`<chrono>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/)

This is part of the Standard C++ library, and as a result you won't have to worry about platform specific implementations (Windows, Linux, ..).

Comment: This is probably better suited as a comment since it does not provide details of converting `GetDateFormat` and `GetTimeFormat`. You should probably offer more than a header file to include.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an equivalent program using standard C++, POSIX [`localtime_r`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime_r) (a thread-safe version of `localtime`) and [`strftime`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
    struct tm t;
    time_t tstamp = time(nullptr);
    if (!localtime_r(&tstamp, &t)) {
        perror("localtime");
        return 1;
    }
    char strdate[16];
    if (strftime(strdate, sizeof(strdate), "%Y-%m-%d", &t) == 0) {
        perror("strftime");
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << strdate << "\n";
    char strtime[16];
    if (strftime(strtime, sizeof(strtime), "%H:%M:%S %p", &t) == 0) {
        perror("strftime");
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << strtime << "\n";
}
```

Unfortunately, Windows doesn't support `localtime_r` but has `localtime_s` which is similar. So to have the above code work on Windows as well, you can add something along the lines

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#  define localtime_r(timet,tm) (!localtime_s(tm,timet))
#endif
```